# When to use buildout:eggs and when to install via zc.recipe.egg?

Tags: python, buildout

There seem to be more than one way to install eggs into a buildout.

### Way 1:

```
[buildout]
...
eggs = 
     eggname
     othereggname
...
```

### Way 2:

```
[buildout]
...
parts = eggs

[eggs]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = eggname
     = othereggname
```

Both ways work. ( variation on way 2 would be to install each requirement as a separate part. )

What is the difference between these 2 methods?

For my projects, I'm using buildout with djangorecipe and mr.developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, the "eggs=" makes those eggs available to that part, which means they're getting installed.

The buildout eggs don't get any additional treatment.

The big difference is that "recipe = zc.recipe.egg" ALSO tries to create scripts for all the eggs defined there.  (Scripts meaning the "console_scripts" entry points, not the old distutils "scripts=", btw)

The way I normally work: I use the eggs in [buildout] to list my most important eggs ("myproject").  In the djangorecipe part, I have basically an "eggs = ${buildout:eggs}".

And a [console_scripts] part with the zc.recipe.egg recipe to make clear that I want console scripts out of the eggs there.  I put extra tools like pep8 in there.

Comment: I think I see the light.  Thanks... I am actually reading your docs ( as I type this. I got them from a different question ) Appreciated.